# Code Spewing Numbers, where it only should be binary

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to read in an 8 digit number to a string, before converting it to an integer. Once converted all I need is to write the numbers out in the console.

Ive tried this with the current code, in visual basic 2019. It runs but gives the wrong output.

```
 Dim num As String
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an 8-Digit binary string")
    num = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim input() As Char = num.ToCharArray()
    Dim array(7) As Integer

    For i = 0 To input.Length - 1

        Dim converted As Integer = Convert.ToUInt16(input(i))
        array(i) = converted
        converted = 0


    Next
```

`

The expected result is to output the exact same as the input, but for it to be in integer form and in an array. It actually outputs numbers in the high 40's.

Comment: Let me see if i understand you right: you want to convert the binary string to a decimal integer, and then return an array where each element represents each digit of that number in base ten? e.g. input = "00101000",  output = {0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0} ?

Comment: what you are doing now in the code you put in your question is converting each digit of the binary inputstring into a base 10 number. but since the digit is either 1 or 0, the decimal output is also 1 or 0. so putting these into an array simply returns an array of 1's and 0's similar to the string you started with.

Comment: If you just want to get the decimal representation from the inputstring and display that, all you need to do is:  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToUInt16(num, 2).ToString()). Provided your input is in a valid format, otherwise you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is exactly with this line:

```vb
Dim converted As Integer = Convert.ToUInt16(input(i))
```

You're passing a `char` to `Convert.ToUInt16` method, which will give you the ASCII representation of the char itself.
Take a look at the [documentation of that method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.touint16?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToUInt16_System_Char_).

Instead you may subtract 48 from it.
Another better option is to use `Char.GetNumericValue` method. You can find its documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Char_GetNumericValue_System_Char_).

The following isn't related to your problem, but why you have the following line ?

```vb
converted = 0
```

It does nothing.

Also, I think the code will look better if you have the declaration and assignment of `num` variable in the same line, but again, this isn't related to your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definately look at improving my code frome here.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.  No need to look at each character.

```
    Dim num As String = ""
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an 8-Digit binary string")
    num = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim theNum As Integer = 0
    If num.Length <= 8 Then
        If Integer.TryParse(num, theNum) Then
            Console.WriteLine(theNum.ToString)
        Else
            'not a number
            Stop
        End If
    Else
        Stop 'too long
    End If
```

edit:  Binary input

```
    Dim num As String = ""
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an 8-Digit binary string")
    num = Console.ReadLine.Trim 'get user input
    If num.Length <= 8 AndAlso num.Length > 0 Then 'did the user enter 8 chars. or less
        For Each c As Char In num 'check that only 0's or 1's where entered
            If Not (c = "0"c OrElse c = "1"c) Then
                Throw New FormatException("error, not binary")
            End If
        Next
        Dim theNum As Integer = 0
        theNum = Convert.ToInt32(num, 2) 'convert to integer
        Console.WriteLine(theNum.ToString)
    Else
        Throw New FormatException("error, check input")
    End If
```

Comment: Won't check if it's only 0s and 1s though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is far too complicated for me to understand yet. I'' look into how it works and maybe change it.

Comment: @OliverDaniells - so one way to learn is to try code you don't understand and use breakpoints to see what is going on.

Comment: Debugger  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Comment: @dbasnett Doesn't do at all what OP asked though. He asked for an array of binary digits. This parses it as one int.

Comment: @Nyerguds - you could be right, but this is confusing, "The expected result is to output the exact same as the input, but for it to be in integer form and in an array."

Answer (score 0):

Get a nice ASCII chart. It will show you that Char 0 is dec 48 and Char 1 is dec 49. That is where your numbers are coming from.

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an 8-Digit binary string")
    Dim num = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim TheDecimalNumber = Convert.ToInt16(num, 2)
    Debug.Print(TheDecimalNumber.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The hexadecimal value of '0' is 0x30 which is 48 in decimal

The hexadecimal value of '1' is 0x31 which is 49 in decimal ...

Hence your result.